# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, is it possible to have $n\sigma(n)=q\sigma(q^k)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**QUESTION**

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, is it possible to have $n\sigma(n)=q\sigma(q^k)$?

**BACKGROUND**

If $\sigma(N)=2N$ (where $\sigma(N)$ is the *sum of the divisors* of $N$), then $N$ is said to be *perfect*. (Denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.)

Euler proved that every odd perfect number has the form $N=q^k n^2$, where $q$ is prime (called the *Euler prime*) satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**MY ATTEMPT TO ANSWER THE QUESTION**

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, and assume to the contrary that $n\sigma(n)=q\sigma(q^k)$.  Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$, this implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Since $\sigma(q^k) \equiv k+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $n$ is odd, then $\sigma(q^k) \neq n$.  This implies that
$$2 \leq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}.$$

But $qn$ and $q^k n$ are both deficient.  This means that
$$\frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\cdot{2} \leq \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} = I(qn) < 2 \implies \frac{\sigma(q)}{n} < 1 \implies q < n,$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}\cdot{2} \leq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} = I({q^k}n) < 2 \implies \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < 1 \implies n < q^k.$$

Together, $q < n$ and $n < q^k$ imply that $k > 1$.  Additionally, the equation
$$n\sigma(n) = q\sigma(q^k)$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{q}{n},$$
which together with $q < n$, implies that
$$\sigma(n) < \sigma(q^k).$$

Consequently, we have
$$q < \sigma(q) < n < \sigma(n) < q^k < \sigma(q^k)$$
so that
$$\frac{\sigma(q)}{n} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n},$$
whereupon I do not obtain any contradictions.

Comment: Since we have the inequality $I(q^k) < I(n)$, then if $n\sigma(n)=q\sigma(q^k)$, we know that
$$\frac{n}{q}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{\sigma(n)}<\frac{q^k}{n}.$$
This implies that $n^2 < q^{k+1}$.

If one could prove the [Dris](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02144) [conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) that $q^k < n$, then we obtain the contradiction
$$q^{2k} < n^2 < q^{k+1} \implies 2k < k + 1 \implies k < 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a answer, only the calculations that I can get (by the nature of the problem concerning odd perfect numbers, one can do deductions with the purpose to prove a more elaborated statement or well with the purpose to finish a proof by contradiction of the statement) . I hope that if there are mistakes some user can tell me.

I prefer the notation $N=q^{4\lambda+1}m^2$, where $q^{4\lambda+1}$ is the Euler's factor associated to the odd perfect number. Since the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$ is multiplicative and $N$ is perfect we've the factorization $$\sigma(q^{4\lambda+1})\sigma(m^2)=2q^{4\lambda+1}m^2.\tag{1}$$ On the other hand we've your condition 
$$m\sigma(m)=q\sigma(q^{4\lambda+1}).\tag{2}$$ Thus multiplying by $\sigma(m^2)$ your condition $(2)$ with the purpose to combine with $(1)$, we get from $$m\sigma(m)\sigma(m^2)=q\sigma(N)=2q^{4\lambda+2}m^2,$$ and thus this

> **Claim 1.** Under previous assumptions $$\sigma(m)\sigma(m^2)=2q^{4\lambda+2}m.\tag{3}$$

Now we search a more elaborated statement combining previous claim with the fact that $$\sigma(m)\cdot\sigma(m^2)\geq (1+m)\cdot(1+m^2+(\sigma(m)-1)),$$ to get $$m^2+\sigma(m)\leq 2q^{4\lambda+2}\frac{m}{m+1},$$ and thus $m^2+\sigma(m)< 2q^{4\lambda+2}$, since $m/(m+1)<1$. From this, we can write

> **Claim 2.** Under previous assumptions $$\sigma(m)<2q^{4\lambda+2}-m^2.$$

Comment: user243301, how do you prove
$$\sigma(m)\cdot\sigma(m^2) \geq (1+m)\cdot(1 + m^2 + (\sigma(m) - 1))?$$

I understand that $\sigma(m) > m + 1$ (since $m$ is composite) but I do not comprehend how you (seemingly) get
$$\sigma(m^2) \geq 1 + m^2 + (\sigma(m) - 1).$$

Comment: Additionally, from your **Claim 1**, I could prove that $\sigma(m) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: user243301, now that you have mentioned it, I just realized that you are right.  =)

Comment: Since $\sigma(m) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, $m$ then takes the form $m = p^{\alpha} {\mu}^2$, where $\gcd(p, \mu)=1$ and $p \equiv \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251542/28816) for a proof of this fact.)

Comment: Many thanks for your reference and attention. Good luck @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris

Answer (score 1):

(What follows are just partial results for the present problem.)

Building from the results in the answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498970), I have
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}=x \in \mathbb{N}.$$

If the immediately preceding equation is true, then
$$xn = \sigma(q^k)$$
$$\sigma(n) = xq$$
$$\sigma\left(\frac{1}{x}\sigma(q^k)\right)=xq.$$
There are no solutions to this last equation for $k>1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, for particular values of $x$.  We have $\sigma(X) \geq X$, where the inequality is strict for $X>1$;  hence,
$$xq=\sigma\left(\frac{1}{x}\sigma(q^k)\right) \geq \frac{1}{x}\sigma(q^k) \geq {\frac{1}{x}}{q^k},$$
so we would need
$$q^{k-1} \leq x^2.$$

But for $k>1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have $k \geq 5$, so that
$$q^{k-1} \geq q^4 \geq 5^4.$$
Hence the original system of equations will only have a solution when
$$x^2 \geq 5^4 \implies x \geq 25.$$
Consequently, we obtain
$$25 \leq \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} = \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}.$$
Multiplying both sides of the inequality and equation by $\sigma(n)/{q^k}$, we get
$${25}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} \leq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} = I({q^k}n) < 2.$$
Multiplying both sides of the inequality and equation by $\sigma(q)/n$, we get
$${25}\cdot\frac{\sigma(q)}{n} \leq \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} = \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} = I(qn) < 2.$$

Therefore, we have $\sigma(n)/{q^k} < 2/{25}$ and $\sigma(q)/n < 2/{25}$, from which it follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} < \frac{2}{25} < 25 \leq \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n}$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(q)}{n} < \frac{2}{25} < 25 \leq \frac{\sigma(n)}{q},$$
whereupon I still do not get any contradictions.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer and serves to add perspective to the problem.

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.

Since it is not possible to have both
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}$$
and
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k},$$
then we know that
$$\lnot\bigg(\left(\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\right) \land \left(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < 1 < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}\right)\bigg)$$
must be true.

Therefore, it must be the case that
$\bigg(\frac{\sigma(q)}{n} < 1\bigg) \lor \bigg(\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} \geq 1\bigg) \lor \bigg(\frac{\sigma(n)}{q^k} \leq 1\bigg) \lor \bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} \geq 1\bigg).$ **(A)**

Towards the end of the original post, it is shown that the problem at hand is equivalent to proving that not all disjuncts in **(A)** are true.